# Some kind of _ref usage in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Consider the following situation: You don't have direct access to the array of a a for loop, e.g.

```
for x, y in [1,2,3]
  console.log x, y, [1,2,3].length
```

where the array [1,2,3] is needed to be typed again to access its length.
This compiles into:

```
var x, y, _i, _len, _ref;

_ref = [1, 2, 3];
for (y = _i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; y = ++_i) {
  x = _ref[y];
  console.log(x, y, [1, 2, 3].length);
}
```

where we see that the variable `_ref` is defined.

`_ref` can as far as I'm concerned be used inside CoffeeScript:

```
for x, y in [1,2,3]
  console.log x, y, _ref.length
```

Works fine, and compiles without any issues.

I can see that this approach could give issues in the following situation:

```
for x, y in [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  continue

for x, y in [1,2,3]
  console.log x, y, _ref.length
```

where `_ref` in the second loop is the first array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, and the array `[1,2,3]` is set to the unused variable `_ref1`

so, are there any ways of solving this problem in a nice way, (except the obvious of defining a variable to `[1,2,3]`)?

Comment: *"so, are there any ways of solving this problem in a nice way"* What problem? Don't use `_ref` directly. No problem. :-) While `_ref` may exist in the output of the CoffeeScript compiler **now**, there's no guarantee it won't be `_r` or `_reference` in the next version. Relying on internals is just a Bad Idea(tm).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In my case specifically I receive the array from two nested functions calls and I don't want to call those functions again to access the length of the array, of course I could just store the array in a variable, but just like the variables x, y are created in the for loop (in the example) it would be nice if there is someway to access the array without having to define it separately. So the problem is that I am lazy and want the array without defining it to an external variable. What you are saying about the usage of internals seems wise :)

Comment: :-) It's really too bad they don't give you `for x, y, a in [1, 2, 3]` or something (where `a` would be a reference to the array), the way JavaScript's built in `forEach` and such do (`[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(entry, index, array) { ... })`). Since that second `,` is currently invalid syntax, you might suggest it to them for a future version. Until then, yeah, a variable is probably your best bet. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ohh! dam :D, to use the forEach function is a perfect solution for me!

Comment: You could also `for e, i in (a = f())` if you wanted to stick with a loop and don't have dogmatic issues with the assignment expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your underlying desire to refer to the array without putting it in a variable first, you could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (or the various others, like [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), etc.). They receive the array reference as their third argument:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach (e, i, a) ->
  console.log e, i, a
```

`e` = entry in the array for this iteration

`i` = index for this iteration

`a` = the array reference

Don't worry about the runtime cost of the function call, [it's near enough to zero that it doesn't matter](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html). Do beware that `this` will have a different meaning within the callback (unless you pass the `thisArg` argument to `forEach`). I don't know whether CoffeeScript gives you syntax sugar that makes that a non-issue (I don't use CoffeeScript)...